# Pandas change multiple columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have a dataset example shown here:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product' : ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'c'],
               'unit' : ['ng/L', 'k/uL', 'x10(3)/mcL', 'x10(3)/mcL', 'k/uL', 'ng/L', 'ng/L', 'sss', 'sss'],
           'value' : [0.2, 1.0, 67.0, 71.5, 23.2, 71.0, 0.44, 59.3, 12.7],
           'market_penetration_rate' : [0.82, 0.64, 77.5, 12.5, 22.5, 88.0, 0.34, 98.2, 87.4]})
```

I want to get all rows where the product = 'a' and the 'unit' = 'ng/l' and convert the value and the unit to be value/1000 and unit = 'ng/ml'

I nearly have it working but I don't know how to get the value and divide by 1000 in the code below

```
df.loc[(df['product'] == 'a') & (df['unit']== 'ng/L'), ['value', 'unit']] = ['value'/1000 ,'ng/mL']
```

In place of 'value'/1000  what do I put? If I just used a constant in the square brackets then it works, but I want to grab the value it already is and divide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, but I think you need to separate the update commands for different operations:

```
mask = df['product'].eq('a') & df['unit'].eq('ng/L') 

# update value
df.loc[mask, 'value'] /= 1000

# update unit
df.loc[mask,'unit']='ng/mL'
```

Output:

```
  product        unit     value  market_penetration_rate
0       a       ng/mL   0.00020                     0.82
1       a        k/uL   1.00000                     0.64
2       c  x10(3)/mcL  67.00000                    77.50
3       c  x10(3)/mcL  71.50000                    12.50
4       d        k/uL  23.20000                    22.50
5       b        ng/L  71.00000                    88.00
6       a       ng/mL   0.00044                     0.34
7       b         sss  59.30000                    98.20
8       c         sss  12.70000                    87.40
```

Comment: oh i never knew about this mask method. THANK YOUU!!

Comment: Hi using the mask method how would I be able to save a column under a different column name if the mask row is true? For example `df.loc[mask, 'value'] = df['age']` i know this code doesn't work but I am wondering how I grab a different column in the same row and save it using the mask method. I have been googling but I can't find anything useful. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, it’s `df.loc[mask, 'new_col'] = df['old_col']`

Comment: so I tried this but it's doing the opposite of what I need technically. I want the value in the age column to be saved in the value of the 'value' column. When I do `df.loc[mask,'age']=df['value']` it saves everything in value to age instead of age to value.

Comment: when I switched to df.loc[mask,'value']=df['age'] I get a key error

Comment: Thanks! I see what you mean now, the new_column is actually a completely new column. So I created the new column     `df.loc[mask, 'altered_value'] = df['age']` and then I included code after to fill the NaN values in 'altered_value' with the values of the 'value' column (which are the rows where the mask=False).
`df.altered_value.fillna(df.value, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Can use df.assign and np.where to compute required values

```
df=df.assign(unit=np.where((df['product'].eq('a'))&(df.unit.eq('ng/L')),'ng/ml', df.unit),value=(np.where((df['product'].eq('a'))&(df.unit.eq('ng/L')),df.value/1000, df.value)))


pr

oduct      unit  value  market_penetration_rate
0       a       ng/ml   0.20                     0.82
1       a        k/uL   1.00                     0.64
2       c  x10(3)/mcL  67.00                    77.50
3       c  x10(3)/mcL  71.50                    12.50
4       d        k/uL  23.20                    22.50
5       b        ng/L  71.00                    88.00
6       a       ng/ml   0.44                     0.34
7       b         sss  59.30                    98.20
8       c         sss  12.70                    87.40
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I ended up doing it the other way since it's easier to read. But I really appreciate your help and it's interesting to see it done this way as well!

Comment: Happy to note it was of help and you have a desirable solution. Please keep coding